# Using ng-cordova with ionic and crosswalk "cordova not found"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova, crosswalk

I'm building an app using Ionic 1.3.1, crosswalk and ng-cordova for accesing the filesystem. I have a path in which I want to create\write a file after the device ready event

```
var storagePath = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory;
```

When I load my app in a browser it outputs to the console
**"ionic.bundle.js:17946 Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined".**
And If I run my app on an android phone it's just a blank white screen.

Comment: You can't use Cordova in the browser, can you try commenting this variable out and testing your application in the browser again?

Comment: I couldn't run it on android as well, so I thought that it was some other issue. Turned out the problem was in my other code. Thanks for the response